# When to run external commands in Python

Tags: python, bash, command

In Python, it's possible to run a bash command to achieve something that can be achieved by running equivalent Python code. As a simple example, to `cd` into a directory and do stuff, you could do either:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('cd directory and do other stuff')
```

or

```
import os
os.chdir(path) # path is the path to the directory
#do other stuff
```

So how do you choose which one to use (I mean in general, not with this simplified example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version just changes the directory of the subprocess. It has no effect on the original Python process, so it's practically useless. It would only be worthwhile if it were part of multiple commands:

```
subprocess.run('cd directory; cat filename', shell=True)
```

The second version changes the directory of the Python process itself.

More generally, if there'a Python function that does the same thing as an external command, you should prefer the function. It's more efficient since it doesn't have to start a new process, it doesn't have to parse the command if you use `shell=True`, and you get more flexible error handling.

Comment: I would add that you should often try to use functions from the standard library. They're guaranteed to be cross platform, are clearer to read, are more efficient, and as shown here are simpler to understand

Comment: Yes I just chose a simple example, but what would be the difference in general in running Python code vs bash commands to achieve a certain task (I'll update my question)

Comment: In general, if there's a function to do something, there's no reason to use an external command for it.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't choose the former. It creates a subprocess and changes to the directory inside that subprocess, which then terminates leaving the Python process's current directory the same as it was before the `subprocess.run` call.

`os.chdir` actually changes the working directory of the current process. Which seems fine until you start using threads and realise that one thread's current directory can be affected by an `os.chdir` call from another thread.

For single-threaded processes (the kind an Ingorant Wandered might typically write initially) this presents no problems.

More broadly, expect to use the `subprocess` module if you need more parallelism than Python can provide alone (research "Python GIL" to find out why naive Python processes can only use one core of a multicore computer).

Comment: Interesting. I'm actually working on a multithreading code example! Thanks for pointing that out it helps

Answer (score 1):

Niether. `subprocess.run('cd directory')` just changed the directory of the subprocess which then exited, discarding that changed-directory context. `os.chdir(path)` is not always insane, just 99% insane. You are better off using `os.path` or `pathlib` to track directories and not changing what "current" means throughout the program.

There is an advantage to running external commands, especially if they implement functionality you don't have at the moment. They can also help parallelize your code such as running an external `grep` and using its results. That has the disadvantage of adding external platform dependencies.

Frequently its only because the programmer happened to understand the shell better than python. Or found a shell example on the net. That's fine for a hobbyist not not a professional code base.

Disclaimer: IMHO

Comment: Calling the use of `os.chdir` "99% insane" is, frankly, ridiculous.

Comment: @chepner - okay, 98%. That's twice as good! From the user perspective "current directory" is the directory the user was in when the command was launched. The user can reasonably expect a relative path to be relative to his cwd. But for GUIs and anything that may get paths from config files or environment variables, or even a GUI dialog, using `os.path` or `pathlib` relative to those variables is the superior path. I am struggling to think of a case I've come across where `os.chdir` was a good idea.

Comment: I'm struggling to think of a good reason to assume the user's home directory will be the current working directory of the program. If you want to make that assumption, starting your program with `os.chdir(os.environ["HOME"])` would be a way to ensure that.

Comment: @chepner - and conversely, `os.chdir` scattered around your code is almost guaranteed to be a debugging nightmare. "foo/bar/baz.txt" worked earlier, why not now?

Comment: @chepnet - I'm stuggling to think of a reason to assume that the user's home directory is a good candidate for forced CWD, regardless of initial point where the program was started. As you say, "HOME" is right there for anything your code needs that is home directory based. No need to `chdir`.

Comment: Treat `os.chdir` like an assignment statement. Mutable global variables are a bad idea; global *constants* are fine. Use `os.chdir` to set the working directory to a know state *once*, then you can use relative paths safely in your code without using `os.path.join` repeatedly. (Or use `os.path.join` as you've mentioned, but again once to define a global constant.)